# Jquery mobile not loads in mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a strange problem, if i load this page in any browser the page displays ok, but when the browser jquery mobile not loads, here the page:

http://www.cuponeraclub.com/landing.html

open it in browser load jquery ok, in mobile jquery mobile not load.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link ref="https://www.cuponeraclub.com/themes/livingsocial_v3.1/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://www.cuponeraclub.com/themes/livingsocial_v3.1/scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.cuponeraclub.com/themes/livingsocial_v3.1/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">   
            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <select id="city">
                                                    <option value="22" >Ambato</option>
                                                    <option value="12" >Cuenca</option>
                                                    <option value="25" >Esmeraldas</option>
                                                    <option value="11" selected>Guayaquil</option>
                                                    <option value="26" >Ibarra</option>
                                                    <option value="27" >Loja</option>
                                                    <option value="24" >Machala</option>
                                                    <option value="28" >Manta</option>
                                                    <option value="29" >Portoviejo</option>
                                                    <option value="10" >Quito</option>
                                                    <option value="23" >Riobamba</option>
                                                    <option value="30" >Santo Domingo</option>
                                            </select></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                    <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="v" data-theme="b">Suscribete</button></div>
            </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->


    <script>
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    alert('undefined');} else {alert('ok');}
    </script>
```

[image]

---

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link ref="https://www.cuponeraclub.com/themes/livingsocial_v3.1/css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="https://www.cuponeraclub.com/themes/livingsocial_v3.1/scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://www.cuponeraclub.com/themes/livingsocial_v3.1/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">   
            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <select id="city">
                                                    <option value="22" >Ambato</option>
                                                    <option value="12" >Cuenca</option>
                                                    <option value="25" >Esmeraldas</option>
                                                    <option value="11" selected>Guayaquil</option>
                                                    <option value="26" >Ibarra</option>
                                                    <option value="27" >Loja</option>
                                                    <option value="24" >Machala</option>
                                                    <option value="28" >Manta</option>
                                                    <option value="29" >Portoviejo</option>
                                                    <option value="10" >Quito</option>
                                                    <option value="23" >Riobamba</option>
                                                    <option value="30" >Santo Domingo</option>
                                            </select></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                    <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="v" data-theme="b">Suscribete</button></div>
            </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->


    <script>
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    alert('undefined');} else {alert('ok');}
    </script>
```

Comment: the scripts are in the hosting with css styles and all

Comment: Can you post the code for it here? Otherwise this question will not be able to stand on it's own once your problem is solved. (and many will simply skip past it refusing to follow the link)

Comment: Don't you still need `<html>` and `<head>` and `<body>` tags?

Comment: the tags are in the page, see the code in browser

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

i modified the link for test, please go here: http://www.cuponeraclub.com/landing.html?mb

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that html code does not have container div with data role page. This div should be parent for present in your html div with data role content.

```
<div data-role='page'>
  <div id="cont" data-role="content" >
  ....
  </div>
</div>
```

And at the moment you have this

```
<body> 
    <div id="cont" data-role="content" ...> 
        <div id="wrap" class="ui-grid-solo">
```

Check the documentation here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

at time I am writing a jQuery Mobile application and just stumbled over that question. Your code is ok in general it seems just your head includes for your libs are not working. Here is your code inside a working head skeleton:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <!-- next one gives arning in browser cause of 'target-densitydpi=device-dpi'
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />

        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="library/jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />-->


        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesIos.css" />-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery.mobile.flatui.css" />

        <!--- scripts -->
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='./library/jquerysoap/jquery.soap.js'></script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="./library/jqueryxml2json/jquery.xml2json.pack.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../library/jqueryxml2json/jquery.xml2json.new.js"></script>
        <script src="../library/jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>


        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" /> 
        <title>Eurofleurs</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // $(document).delegate(".ui-content", "scrollstart", false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">   
                <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                    <div class="ui-block-a"><input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <select id="city" data-role="ui-select">
                            <option value="22" >Ambato</option>
                            <option value="12" >Cuenca</option>
                            <option value="25" >Esmeraldas</option>
                            <option value="11" selected>Guayaquil</option>
                            <option value="26" >Ibarra</option>
                            <option value="27" >Loja</option>
                            <option value="24" >Machala</option>
                            <option value="28" >Manta</option>
                            <option value="29" >Portoviejo</option>
                            <option value="10" >Quito</option>
                            <option value="23" >Riobamba</option>
                            <option value="30" >Santo Domingo</option>
                        </select></div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-solo">
                    <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="v" data-`enter code here`theme="b">Suscribete</button></div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /content -->
        </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```